# Turn off the notification sound when I turn the phone on

Tags: notifications

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S3
Model: GT-19305
Version: 4.4.4

Good day! I want to know if there is a way to turn the notification sound off every time I turn my phone on. It is unnecesary.

Thanks!
Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just turning notification sound off completely then?

1. Go to *Settings › Sound*
2. If it exists and is switched on, switch off "Use same volume for ringtone and notifications"
3. Now set the notification volume level to zero.

In case the system changes that back to default on reboot, you could use some [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) app like [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) (might be a bit overkill) or any other simpler solution (see my app listings on [Automation (Profile Switching and more)](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation) for possible candidates). Several of them should support actions on-boot (Tasker does), or alternatively let you have a profile valid from 0:00-23:59 (i.e. always) you could assing the task "set notification volume off".

Comment: Thank you! I just turned the system notification sound completely off.

Comment: Glad to be of help! If you consider this solving your issue, please tick the check-mark next to the answer to indicate such (makes it easier for other folks in similar situations to identify solutions). Thanks, and enjoy!